# Crop image in HTML5

Tags: html, image

how to crop an image in html? I have an image on server-pc, is it possible to put only a cropped portion on my webpage without explicitly cropping and creating a new image?

Answer (score 4):

You have two options really.

**1)** is to use image modification scripts to reproduce a cropped image, like TimThumb (requires PHP). This will crop the image dynamically. It's unclear from your question whether you don't want a new image at all, or whether you just don't want to create one manually.

**2)** is to do something nifty with HTML/CSS. Basically you'd create a container for your image, hide the overflow, and position/resize the image within it. It'll be something like this...

HTML:

```
<div class="crop">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.crop {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
}
.crop img {
    left: -20px; /* alter this to move left or right */
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px; /* alter this to move up or down */
}
```